# Hej. I have the next question about GPS status in android

Tags: gps, state

Hej. I have the next question . I need to observe gps status changing and if it's off I need to show some dialog in my screen . Another way if it been on, I need to automatically run some function to get weather info . I use Jetpack compose, clean architecture  and mvi pattern . I try to make it using BroadcastReceiver but I don't know how to update flow state in viewmodel from broadcast receiver. Maybe there are some options?

If its possible I need to update data all time the gps status changing and by gps state update my ui